# httpd 2.4 mod_rewrite negative/inverse match

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to setup an (httpd 2.4 / mod_rewrite) redirect as the following:

- *redirect:*    http://**admin**.site.com/anything  ->  http://**www**.site.com/anything
- *pass though:* http://**admin**.site.com/user ->  http://**admin**.site.com/user
- *pass though:* http://**www**.site.com/anything -> http://**www**.site.com/anything

I have tried the follwowing:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

I could get the **^/user** to match positive and proceed to the next RewriteRule, but I can't get the **!^/user** to match and proceed to RewriteRule.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [NC,L,R,NE]
```

This will redirect the whole subdomain (except /user) to your main domain.